# Disable client side decorations in Nautilus (Gnome 3.10)

Tags: gnome, nautilus, csd

If I open a Nautilus window via terminal using `sudo` or `gksudo` command, client side decorations seem to be disabled and I get the “old style” windows decorations:

[image]

Can someone retrace this behavior? Since I happen to dislike the new CDS, I’d really like to get title bars *everytime* I open Nautilus.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome 3.10 installed from the official repo.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to change the desktop environment:

```
sudo env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=UNITY nautilus
```

To make it permanent, just copy the file with:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

for copying `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/`

Then run `gksudo nautilus` where `gksudo` because you run GUI app.
Or,

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications/ && gksudo nautilus .
```

where dot will point nautilus to directory. Or even:

```
gksudo nautilus ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

And change the lines:

> `Exec=nautilus --new-window`

To:

> `Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=UNITY nautilus --new-window`

Save file and enjoy your Unity.